# Install Maven on Ubuntu

Tags: maven, ubuntu-12.04

I am not able to install maven in Ubuntu 12.04

I tried : sudo apt-get install maven

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package maven is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'maven' has no installation candidate
```

when i run : apt-cache search maven

```
libapache-pom-java - Maven metadata for all Apache Software projects
libcommons-parent-java - Maven metadata for Apache Commons project
maven-ant-helper - helper scripts for building Maven components with ant
maven-repo-helper - Helper tools for including Maven metadata in Debian packages
libjenkins-plugin-parent-java - Jenkins Plugin Parent Maven POM
```

I am getting a message like this. How to resolve this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First search for Maven package....

For that run this command in terminal..

```
apt-cache search maven
```

Then install...

```
sudo apt-get install maven
```

And at last for verification...

```
mvn -version
```

Hope this will help you....  ;)

Answer (score 2):

Download maven from apache maven official site and extract.

Move the application directory to /usr/local

```
sudo cp -R apache-maven-X.X.X /usr/local
```

Make a soft link in /usr/bin for universal access of mvn

```
sudo ln -s /usr/local/apache-maven-X.X.X/bin/mvn /usr/bin/mvn
```

Verify mvn installation

```
mvn --version
```